# Creating Javascript Object Array from a String REST response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I am unsure if I am trying to achieve the impossible here, javascript is not my strong point.

This is the data structure that I need, in javascript, in order to populate a chart using google-charts:

```
injuryDistChart.data = [['X', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
  [1, 2, null, null, null, null, null],
  [2, 2, 3, null, null, null, null],
  [3, 2, null, 4, null, 6, null],
  [4, null, null, null, 5, null, null],
  [5, null, null, null, null, 6, null],
  [6, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [7, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [8, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [9, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [10, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7]
];
```

The response I am generating from the server is as follows. It is a String NOT a JSON response:

```
"[['X', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
  [1, 2, null, null, null, null, null],
  [2, 2, 3, null, null, null, null],
  [3, 2, null, 4, null, 6, null],
  [4, null, null, null, 5, null, null],
  [5, null, null, null, null, 6, null],
  [6, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [7, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [8, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [9, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],
  [10, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7]
]"
```

Is there a way to transform this String object into the 3-D array, or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Should I rather send back a JSON response, and transform that into the 3-D array I need?

I am using Java RESTful WS, angular and google charts.

Comment: Google ALWAYS have JSON API somwhere for given service. So if that is not JSON, then go look for better API its there ;)

Comment: Just use `"` instead of `'` and this will make a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally sending back JSON is the preferred method. If this isn't possible all you need to do in this instance is convert the single quotes to double quotes to make it valid JSON and then parse it like normal.

```
const json = str.replaceAll("'", '"');
injuryDistChart.data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Example:

```js
const json = "[['X', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],[1, 2, null, null, null, null, null],[2, 2, 3, null, null, null, null],[3, 2, null, 4, null, 6, null],[4, null, null, null, 5, null, null],[5, null, null, null, null, 6, null],[6, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[7, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[8, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[9, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[10, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7]]";
const json2 = json.replaceAll("'", '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(json2))
```

Comment: `replace(/'/g, '"');`

Comment: So, I changed the single quotes to double quotes, serverside, and then used JSON.parse(), and it all worked

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()` on the string you get back if you can't send back a JSON object from your service to parse the string into a JSON object, but ideally, yes, you should have the response type on your service set to `json`.

Comment: I can send JSON back, but I thought that the format I have posted above, was the only format it takes. It looks like google charts does have a JSON api, which is what I need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = "[['X', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],[1, 2, null, null, null, null, null],[2, 2, 3, null, null, null, null],[3, 2, null, 4, null, 6, null],[4, null, null, null, 5, null, null],[5, null, null, null, null, 6, null],[6, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[7, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[8, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[9, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7],[10, 2, null, null, 5, null, 7]]"
const json2 = eval(json)
console.log(json2)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pushpendra_Rawat/oq5ntva6/3/

Comment: `eval` is unsafe. It can easily be exploited by providing a response with malicious code